# .NET Core 3 (Preview) - Package version conflicts

Tags: asp.net-core

I currently have the following packages in my .NET Core application.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
```

I am trying to add some logging.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog/3.0.0-preview6.19304.6

But when I try, I get the following error message...

> Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms from
>   3.0.0-preview6.19303.8 to 3.0.0-preview5.19224.8. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
>
> MyApp -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog 3.0.0-preview6.19304.6
>   -> System.Diagnostics.EventLog 4.6.0-preview6.19303.8 -> Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 3.0.0-preview6.19303.8)
>
> MyApp -> Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 3.0.0-preview5.19224.8)

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: First rule, don't mix package vessions. Second rule: don't mix package versions ;) Use all packages as preview5 or preview6, not both, because every will pull a lot of other dependencies. If you target / have .NET Core preview6 installed, use all the preview6 packages. Same for preview5

Comment: @Tseng I have failed you. I actually did upgrade them all to preview6, but rolled back to post here with a cleaner version. However, it still wanted to downgrade my Platforms to preview5. However, I just spotted the SDK is preview5, not preview6. I will fix that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, the error means that one or more of the package references actually *already* has a reference to one of your other package references. In this case, that almost certainly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, where one or perhaps both of your other two references actually reference this package already. However, since they have a higher preview version, they're referencing a higher preview version of `NewtonsoftJson` as well, and your explicit project reference to a lower preview version is causing a "downgrade".

The solution is simple: either 1) update your project reference to the latest, so that it matches with the internal reference in the other package(s) or 2) just remove the package reference entirely. If the package is already brought in as a dependency for another package, you can use it as well via the existing reference; you do not need to explicitly reference it yourself.